# Vim and Notepad++ show different indentation

Tags: vim

Previously I mainly used Notepad++, and used it to develop many SQL scripts. In Notepad++, the indent are fine. Now I switched to Vim, but found many lines indented well in Notepad++, are not indented correctly in Vim.

e.g in Notepad++, it shows

```
   declare @a int
   declare @b int
   declare @c int
```

But when open in Vim, it shows

```
  declare @a int
       declare @b int
 declare @c int
```

If I fix it in Vim, then when I open it using Notepad++, the format is messed up. Why does it happen, and how to fix it?

Comment: You're probably indenting with some combination of spaces and tabs, and then Vim has a different tab width set.

Comment: Marius gave the correct answer already. You might want to look into `:help 'listchars'` to get a better visual feedback of such whitespace mixing.

Comment: [Tabs are evil](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TabsAreEvil)

Comment: @mouviciel: Linking to an emacs page on a Vim question. Priceless. :)

Comment: @bitmask - I am more open-minded about vim vs. emacs than about spaces vs. tabs :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Marius gave the correct answer in comment, I suggest using

```
set listchars=tab:»·,trail:·
set list
```

in your `.vimrc`. It will display tabulations and trailing spaces at the end of lines.

You might also want, but this is a matter of personal reference, to add the following to make sure, that every every time you use <kbd>Tab</kbd>, you actually insert the same number of spaces. In my example, a tabulation corresponds to 4 spaces, but you can use something else.

```
set shiftwidth=4             " used by >>, << and tab.
set tabstop=4                " number of space characters used when displaying TAB
set expandtab                " replace TAB by spaces
set softtabstop=4            " will erase 4 spaces at once when using BS in the begining of lines only
```

Finally, to apply these new settings to an existing file, you might want to run on your file.

```
:%retab
```

Be aware that different editors tend to by default, display different width whenever <kbd>Tab</kbd> is used, this can be useful if different people want their code to be laid out differently, but this is also tends to break the indentation when not carefully used.

I think the best solution is still to use tab for indentation, spaces for alignment, but this is hard to maintain. See an example [there](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Indent_with_tabs,_align_with_spaces). The dumb and fullproof solution is to use spaces every where, and this is the set up I have just described.